# What should be in a base page object?

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects

When building an automation framework some examples I see use a "Base Page" object that all other Page Objects derive from.

Typically these include a default constructor passing whatever `driver` or `session` needed, along with a `open` or `goto` method that defines the URL of the page (Which the `Base` page object is typically just the default url).

However I'm having a hard time coming up with a real need for a Base page object outside of that.

Some people suggest storing "common" locators that all pages see (Floating headers/footers/etc...) but isn't it better to store those in components?

I suppose you could also put in common UI actions/methods in here, but again those seem to usually be in utility classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I'm having a hard time coming up with a real need for a Base
> page object outside of that.

Remember [You Ain't Gonna Need It](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html): Solve your problem simply; to not try to find opportunities to create code. Code is trash, it gets complicated and costly to change. The less you build to solve your problem, the better.

> Some people suggest storing "common" locators that all pages see
> (Floating headers/footers/etc...) but isn't it better to store those
> in components?

This may increase the level of coupling your code have. It's the typical case where you should [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354) and to improve the naming of your classes.

A master *BasePage* with components such as headers and footers will work until you have pages without headers, footers. You may ended, by mistake, using this *BasePage* in these different pages - it will compile and work, but your concrete page will have more behavior that necessary/capable of doing.

Try to create components that you can inject base locators/web elements, and they will have behavior hidden in the class.

E.g. here we have two instance of a... QuestionLinkList:

[image]

```
class QuestionLinkList {

    QuestionLinkList(WebElement base) { this.base = base; }

    public void clickOnLinkAt(Int position) { 
      base.findElements(ITEM_LOCATOR).get(position).click();
      enter code here
    }
}
```

Then on the QuestionPage, you can say you have two instances of this component:

```
class QuestionPage {

    QuestionPage(WebDriver driver) { 
      this.relatedQuestions = new QuestionLinkList(driver.findElement(RELATED_QUESTIONS));
      this.hotNetworkQuestions = new QuestionLinkList(driver.findElement(HOT_NETWORK_QUESTIONS));
    }
}
```

With time, discovering similarities in the pages or duplications in your code, you can enhance your library of components, creating components of components, etc.

I would suggest using inheritance when you indeed **discover specific types of pages or components**.

For instance, you can have an abstract *BasePage* that holds a *WebDriver* and has a `goto` method. You can have an abstract *SearchablePage*, that inherits from *BasePage*, and has a **private** search bar component and provide the method `searchFor(String)`. And then you can the *QuestionPage* and the *HomePage*, both inheriting from *SearchPage* - because both are pages that you can search stuff over: You inherit the method/behavior, not the component.

> utility classes

Here you may be creating spaghetti code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340057) is a detailed explanation of why.

Comment: This is a good point, I have a hard time of really seeing how it "saves" code tbh. And this is a good explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Mercfh. If you found the answer satisfactory, could you mark it as accepted, so other will know that it tackles the question?